# How long does it take to get a EEA Family Permit?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, eu

I am a French citizen, married to a Russian citizen. I now live and work in the UK, and from what we read, the best solution for her to join me is to apply to a EEA Family Permit, and once in the UK, she'd need to apply for a residence card.

Anyway. How long does it take usually to get the family permit? From the application to the actual delivery of the visa…

Comment: Technically applying for a residence card is not mandatory. But having one is useful, especially to travel in and out of the UK.

Comment: I have applied for a family permit 15 weeks ago and up to date nothing has come out but when I applied at the Embassy the person who attended me said if I leave the passport it will be quicker between 3 to 5 weeks, I fill it not fare from they part kipping a passport because if you want to travel outside EU you can't do it because they simply old your personal document with them.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a source at hand but it used to be a huge problem. EU law says “quickly” and the Commission considers delays longer than 4 weeks unacceptable. Visas for EU citizens family members are also supposed to be handled in priority. But a few years ago, application for EEA family permits actually took 6 months or more to be processed. I have no idea whether the issue has been resolved.

[There are also other issues with EEA Family permits](https://eumovement.wordpress.com/2014/08/07/is-uk-handling-of-eea-family-permit-visas-still-a-problem/).

Comment: Thank you. The stories in your link are not very enthusiastic, but at least, it gives me an idea of the problems I may have to face...